# What is the ranking of the Big Ten in 2080?

Tags: lore, shadowrun-6th-world

What is the ranking of the Big Ten in 2080, and how does it differ from what we had in sr5's Market Panic in 2078?

The ranking then was:

1. Mitsuhama Computer Technologies
2. Saeder Krupp
3. Renraku
4. Aztechnology
5. Shiawase
6. Wuxing
7. Evo
8. SpinGlobal
9. Ares Macrotechnology
10. Horizon

Ideally, a ranking would describe how those changes came to be or directly refer to the pages where I can read about how those changes occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the rankings on Pages 23 and 24 of the "Sixth World Core Rulebook: City Edition: Seattle". It doesn't appear to have changed from the list you provided, but this ranking is listed with "2080" as the date in this book.

The ranking is as follows:

1. Mitsuhama Computer Technologies
2. Saeder-Krupp
3. Renraku
4. Aztechnology
5. Shiawase
6. Wuxing
7. EVO Corporation
8. Spinrad Global
9. Ares Macrotechnology
10. Horizon